# GTK in CodeBlocks no deflateSetHeader in zlib1.dll

Tags: gtk, codeblocks, zlib

I'm attempting to get a working GTK project in Code::Blocks on a Windows machine. I followed the instructions found under the "Simple Way" at this [link](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8908)

When I open up a GTK project and attempt to compile and run, I get the following error message:

```
The procedure entry point deflateSetHeader could not be located in the dynamic 
link library zlib1.dll.
```

Is there a more recent version of zlib1.dll that I need to replace the current one with? If so, does there exist a link? Or perhaps if anyone else has had a similar error, any feedback would be very much obliged.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to install StarDict-editor in my Windows XP computer.

I got the installer stardict-editor-3.0.1.rar from http://code.google.com/p/stardictproject/downloads/list
and tried to install StarDict-editor without GTK but was impossible because a lot of messages reporting .dll files missing.

Finally the solution was:

1. Install first the GTK+ for Windows Runtime Environment from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-win/?abmode=1
   In the installation options mark an option saying something like "install dll files..."
2. Try again to install stardict-editor.exe
3. Then I got the mentioned error message: "The procedure entry point deflateSetHeader could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll"
4. I looked in my computer for zlib1.dll files and find several versions.
5. Choose from the list of files, the more recently created zlib1.dll. Copy this file and paste the copy in the path: c:\Windows\system32 (this is for Windows XP)
6. Now, try again the installation stardict-editor.exe
7. StarDict-editor installed and working ok, it seems.

Comment: This worked out fine! thank you very much for your answer. Also for future reference: If you are reading this and having problems with compiling a stardict dictionary from tabbed txt files due to "duplicate entry" errors, use 3.0.1 instead of the newest version.

Comment: This solution works, but make sure than when you're using virtualenv you copy dll into virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Check the output window to find out where it's loading zlib1.dll from. For me, the log read "Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\zlib1.dll'".

I couldn't get it to load the right dll by changing my path and had to replace the dll in SysWOW64 with the newer version in order for my project to compile.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, instead of doing hazardous deletions within the windows system folders, you can also copy the correct dll alongside the executable that you are trying to launch.